# Как передать данные "загрузки" cpu в программу на с\с++?

Tags: c++, linux, c, ubuntu

Суть в следующем: я хочу передать в программу на с\с++ данные о загрузке cpu или gpu(например, температуру) на linux(ubuntu 16.04), но не используя при этом посторонних утилит типа lm sensors. Т.е. я хочу извлекать данные напрямую с датчиков(если это возможно) и передавать их в программу для дальнейших действий, либо как-то получать эти данные в процессе работы программы. Видел много ответов по поводу подобных действий с использованием winapi, но под linux что-то не нашел(или проглядел). **А теперь, внимание, вопрос: мб кто-то сталкивался с этим\писал что-то подобное\знает что гуглить на эту тему или даже вдруг знает, как это реализовать?** Заранее благодарен!

Comment: смотреть исходники lmsensors
там все есть
они обращаются к модулям ядра, которые могут записать/прочитать "железный" порт
из userspace, насколько я знаю, не получится обращение к портам железа
вот тут есть более правильный ответ http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42980/can-hardware-be-accessed-directly-from-user-space

Comment: К слову, пока ждал тут ответа порылся на англоязычном stackoverflow и нашел довольно грамотно оформленный код по теме: https://github.com/spinlockirqsave/examples/blob/master/cpu/cpu_temperature/main.cpp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Непосредственно с датчиков вы эти данные никак не получите. Ядро linux не позволит пользовательскому приложению обращаться напрямую к оборудованию. Кроме того, вам фактически придется реализовывать собственный lm_sensors, потому как на разных чипсетах данные получаются различным образом и по факту нужны драйвера для каждого конкретного датчика. Драйвера датчиков в linux уже есть и они как раз зовутся lm_sensors (ядерная часть, а не утилита). Обратите внимание, в windows точно так же, есть драйвера в ядре и есть интерфейс winapi.

В linux получить всю информацию от драйверов датчиков, а так же управлять некоторыми параметрами (скоростью вращения вентиляторов и пределами) можно через файловый интерфейс `/sys/class/hwmon` и `/sys/bus/platform/devices/coretemp.0`. Описание интерфейса можно найти в файле `Documentation/hwmon/sysfs-interface` исходников ядра.

Загрузку процессоров можно посчитать на основе данных из файла `/proc/stat`. Описание этого интерфейса можно найти в `Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt` исходников ядра.

Comment: Если бы мне позволила репутация, я бы проголосовал за ваш ответ :) Но увы, зарегался только сегодня.

Comment: @Shadr, для полноценного уровня Вам надо набрать 300 (а вот голосовать *за* можно уже с 15 (см. [список привилегий](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges))

Comment: @Mike, я тут поискал по указанному вами адресу, но у меня там только makefile :) И вообще в системе нет файла proc.txt, но в man'е описание интерфейса, естесна, оказалось. Там везде говорится о некоем time, и что-то мне подсказывает, что именно на основе этого "времени" как раз и

Comment: (Прошу прощения, случайно ткнул в энтр) @Mike, я тут поискал по указанному вами адресу, но у меня там только makefile :) И вообще в системе нет файла proc.txt, но в man'е описание интерфейса, естесна, оказалось. Там везде говорится о некоем time, и что-то мне подсказывает, что именно на основе этого "времени" как раз и

Comment: Короче, руки из жопы у меня :) 

Так вот, мне кажется, что на основе этого time и можно как вы говорите, посчитать загрузку, но уровень знаний не позволяет даже прикинуть как это делается. Посему возник еще вопрос: возможно вы в курсе, как это считается и можете поделиться опытом или есть какая-то литература, где это можно быстро посмотреть(чтобы не пришлось осваивать большой объем материала ради этого) или, опять же, google it for me, потому что я не знаю даже, что в таком случае гуглят :)

Comment: @Shadr Никогда этим не занимался. А исходники ядра у вас в системе видимо не лежат. Можно взять на kernel.org. Что касается расчета - то возьмите последний procps: http://procps.sourceforge.net/  и изучите исходники `top.c` . Непосредственно расчетом занимается функция `summaryhlp()` как видно из нее она суммирует несколько видов загрузки и вычитает из них предыдущие значения и на основе этого выводит процент. информацию из /proc/stat читает `cpus_refresh()`